# Directive to dynamically create an ng-pattern

Tags: dynamic, angularjs, directive

I'm trying to create a directive for an `input` element that will dynamically create an `ng-pattern` to check for a valid IP address in the input field. All of my attempts to do so have been completely unsuccessful.  While I can dynamically modify other attributes, I can't create an `ng-pattern` that will affect the `$valid` status.

Here's the code that I've been working on which seems like it should work, but it doesn't do anything to the `ng-pattern`.

```
app.directive('ipAddress', function($parse) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.ngPattern);
            model.assign(scope, "/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/");
            scope.$apply();
        };
});
```

Directive:

```
<input ng-model="ip" ip-address required type="text" id="inputIP" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx">
```

Yes, I know I can just specify the `ng-pattern` inline with the `<input>` tag but the point is that I want to be able to do this dynamically in the code, and I'd like to keep the `<input>` tag cleaner by not embedding a bunch of regex code there.

Can anyone please help me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define pattern in controller and then use in html:

```
$scope.pat=/^.*$/
```

And then in html

```
<input ng-pattern="pat" ... >
```

Comment: That's really good (thanks!), but I was hoping for a way to set the ngPattern variable inside the directive so that the HTML element doesn't even need to have the "ng-pattern" attribute defined.

Comment: Look here: http://piotrbuda.eu/2013/02/angularjs-directive-for-password-matching.html The trick here is that "ctrl.$parsers.push" is called when Angular try to move data to model. You can prevent this, by not returning value. As in this example you can also set validity for input. Based on this example I have build input that allows only numbers to be entered. You can do the same with IP.

Comment: actually the proposed solution by @user2543349 doesn't work. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/8JzDb/70/ If I replace ng-pattern="mypattern" with ng-pattern="/^\d*$/" it works as expected accepting only numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not quote patterns in code. Try exactly (without ' ): $scope.mypattern = /^\d*$/;

Answer (score 1):

Although you would like an answer without the use of ng-pattern but I would suggest you not use a directive for that as using it would not add much benefits over the use of another file to include in your code.

Rather I would suggest you use **constants** to make your pattern globally available so other forms can use it too, like a directive but without the overhead.

You can declare a constant like:

`app.constant('FORMATS', {
    "ipAdressRegex": /^your-regex-here)*$/i
});`

And use this constant in your controller or service :

```
var Controller = app.controller('Controller', ['$scope','FORMATS',
function ($scope,FORMATS) {

    $scope.ipAddressPattern = FORMATS.ipAdressRegex;
    .
    .
    .
```

In your view :

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"
       id="input_ip" name="email" data-ng-model="user.ip_add"
       data-ng-pattern="ipAddressRegex" />
```

Also further if you only want to use it in your views you can instead add the constant in your **$rootScope** instead of creating a local scope variable in the controller:

So instead of

```
$scope.ipAddressPattern = FORMATS.ipAdressRegex;
```

You can do in your **config.js**

```
_.assign($rootScope, _.pick(FORMATS, 'ipAddressRegex'));
```

View will remain as before