# AngularJS 1.3 pattern validation binding not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern, angularjs-bindings

I have been using Regex pattern validation with AngularJS for the last several versions and it has worked fine.

My application requires that validation patterns are exposed by a scope property, to which the corresponding AngularJS validation directive is bound. Prior to v1.3, it looked something like this:

```
// On the controller
$scope.validationPattern = "^\\d*$"; // Allow only numeric digits

<!-- in the HTML page --->
<input type="text" name="age" ng-pattern="/{{validationPattern}}/" />
```

Having now updated AngularJS to v1.4 (bypassing v1.3), I find that the above approach no longer works. Looking at the [migration notes for v1.3](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration), I see that this is expected behavior and that a new approach is required, which looks something like this:

```
// On the controller
$scope.validationRegexp = /^\d*$/; // Use a RegExp instead of a string

<!-- in the HTML page --->
<input type="text" name="age" pattern="{{validationRegexp}}" />
```

However, I simply can't get this to work. If I place the validation pattern inline (within the HTML input element) it works fine, but when moved onto the scope object and bound to the `pattern` or `ng-pattern` directive, no validation occurs.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/461/) that demonstrates the problem.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directive to dynamically create an ng-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384909/directive-to-dynamically-create-an-ng-pattern)

Comment: You need only the scope variable name: ng-pattern="validationPattern"

Comment: @Fals. Yes, you're right that it works with just the scope variable name in ng-pattern. It seems that the release notes are wrong. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only the name of the scope variable:

```
<input type="text" name="age" ng-pattern="validationPattern" />
```