# AngularJS Date Pattern Validation Changes from v1.3 to v1.4

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323111) about the changes to RegExp pattern validation that were introduced in AngularJS v1.3. The answer I received apparently solved my problem, but now I am trying to apply that approach, and I see that the behavior is again different in AngularJS v1.4.

Specifically, I want to apply pattern validation to a date input field, but the validation RegExp will be exposed as a property of the model, instead of being hard-coded into the form markup.

As suggested, I am specifying the name of the model property in the ng-pattern attribute ...

```
<input type="date" ng-model="myDate" name="myDate" ng-pattern="control.dateRegex" />
```

... and exposing the validation RegExp as a property of the model:

```
$scope.control = {
    dateRegex: /^2015-\d+-\d+$/
};
```

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/500/) shows it working correctly with AngularJS v1.3 and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/502/) demonstrates that the same implementation does not work with v1.4. I am unable to find any documentation that describes the correct implementation for use with v1.4.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: @Daniel Haley thanks. I have updated the Fiddle and edited the link above to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking [a similar question](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12344#issuecomment-121194445) on the AngularJS issues forum, I learned that this behavior is specific to date input validation. It arises because the model property used for date input binding has changed from a `String` to a `Date` object, which means that is no longer possible to use a RegExp to validate it.

It seems that the AngularJS team recognize this as a bug and that we can expect a fix in a forthcoming release. I will monitor the issue and update this thread when there is some progress.